# Using array_key_exists

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that's accessed via `$request` (this is not the same as `$_REQUEST`). The array print_r's out as

```
Array
(
    [num_days] => 30
    [customer_id] => 5
)
```

The `num_days` key may or may not exist (it can be any number of things.) I need to test to see if the key exists. I've tried this:

```
if(array_key_exists($request['num_days'], $request)) {
    echo "num_days exists";
}
else {
    echo "num_days doesn't exist";
}
```

This always hits the else. Am I doing this wrong? Is num_days not considered a key? If not, how can I test for the existence of that element (NOT the value of it, but whether it exists at all)?

Comment: `array_key_exists('num_days', $request)`

Comment: @DanielM: `isset()` and `array_key_exists()` are not totally the same.  If the value was set, but was `NULL`, then `isset()` would return `false`, but `array_key_exists()` would return `true`.

Comment: Thank you, @Orbling. If you want to post as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: No need, simple misunderstanding, one term answer.  No idea why it was marked down, the question and mistake may be simple, but there was nothing wrong with it.  Negative marks are not supposed to be punishment for lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is wrong

array_key_exists — Checks if the given key or index exists in the array

**Your code with array_key_exists** [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
if(array_key_exists('num_days', $request)) {
    echo "num_days exists";
}
else {
    echo "num_days doesn't exist";
}
```

**Alternative method with isset** [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
   if(isset($_REQUEST['num_days'])) {
        echo "num_days exists";
    }
    else {
        echo "num_days doesn't exist";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use either `array_key_exists('num_days', $request)` or `isset($request['num_days'])`

What you are doing is **wrong** and just checks if the value of that array elements exists as a key.